# Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured

Tags: phpmyadmin

Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.

Comment: What is your problem you copy pasted an error message?

Comment: well the pages are not loading from the htdocs folder from xamp

Comment: Did you tried to restart apache with the control panel from xampp?

Comment: yes I tried in the browser its showing ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Do you have something else on port 80, skype maybe?

Comment: no.
apachectl configtest
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Pranavs-Mac-mini-5.local for ServerName

Comment: this is what it shows wien I ran apachectl configtest in terminal

Comment: Anything in the Apache error log?